# Sharepoint Taxonomy TaxCatchALL?

Tags: taxonomy

Why is TaxCatchALL so important with a Managed Meta Data field?

Can it affect filtering of items based on a managed meta data field?

Comment: we saw in an ITEM UPDATING state, this field has the old data for the term even though we were on the AFTERPROPERTIES and we had changed the field on the UI.... this field is not making any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TaxCatchAll field is necessary to get Refinements search to work. The field catches al values from all managed metadata fields into those field.